# git-p4 clone command fails

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I'm trying to run this command: git-p4 clone -v //depot/path/project/v31a

And it fails with error:

Importing from //depot/path/project into project

Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/xxx/Downloads/p4tmp/v31a/.git/

Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', '--bool', 'git-p4.useclientspec']

Doing initial import of //depot/path/project/v31a/ from revision #head into refs/remotes/p4/master

Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', 'git-p4.user']

Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', 'git-p4.password']

Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', 'git-p4.port']

Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', 'git-p4.host']

Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', 'git-p4.client']

Opening pipe: ['p4', '-G', 'files', '//depot/path/project/v31a/...#head']

Opening pipe: ['p4', '-G', 'describe', '-s', '222342']

Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', '--bool', 'core.ignorecase']

commit into refs/remotes/p4/master

Opening pipe: p4 -G users

**IO error with git fast-import. Is your git version recent enough?**

==============================================

Before this, I have set P4HOST, P4USER AND P4PASSWD environment variables.

Any idea what this error is? My git version is 2.3.6.

Comment: You need to specify your destination folder as a last command: `git-p4 clone -v //depot/path/project/v31a C:\DestinationFolder`

Answer (score 3):

That error happens if Python can't talk to `git fast-import`. You could check that it's actually installed:

`$ git fast-import -h`

You might also get it if git-p4 can't create temporary files for some reason. Running your command under `strace` might offer some more clues as to what's happening.

What OS are you running on?